# Swift - How to hide back button in navigation item?

Tags: ios, swift

Right now I have two view controllers. My problem is I don't know how to hide the back button after transitioning to the second view controller. Most references that I found are in Objective-C. How do I code it in Swift?

Hide back button code in Objective-C

```
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 466, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationitem/1624934-sethidesbackbutton) for `UINavigationItem` :

```
self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: true)
```

Comment: the snarkiness is for free.

Comment: It might frighten you @Paulw11, but the plain fact is typing "Swift hide back button" into Google and coming here - like I just did - is *tons* quicker than ploughing through the reams of text in the official documentation.

Comment: Whereas the name of the back button is defined in the first view controller, it may be interesting to notice that the code to hide it must be implemented in the second view controller (the one showing the button).

Answer (score 54):

In case you're using a `UITabBarController`:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
}
```

Comment: Same for me, however I would like to understand why. Does anyone knows what is the difference between the accepted answer and this approach? The only thing I can think of is the inheritance model vs a static version of the navigation bar.

Comment: @HelmutGranda If you notice that Bruno is using a Tab Bar Controller, that is the difference. In the accepted answers' case, the VC is likely embedded in a navigation controller.

Comment: @cloudcal I'm not using a tabBar, yet both answers worked. Both of them hid the back button. I thought they'd behave different if the viewController was *on the screen* and then I wanted to hide the back button. Yet again they both acted the same. I wasn't able find any difference between them. I'm saying Bruno's answer is incorrect. Rather for pure navigationController it doesn't make a difference. I haven't tried tabBarController

Comment: ```override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
    }```

Answer (score 27):

Swift

```
// remove left buttons (in case you added some)
 self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = []
// hide the default back buttons
 self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
```

Comment: It's clear that navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true is the right answer.  If there are left buttons, which can be the case, then this is most definitely the right answer, and should be considered the more complete answer.

Comment: `self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true` Its working as expected.

Comment: In my case with several navigationControllers only this helped: **self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = []**

Answer (score 10):

This is also found in the UINavigationController class documentation:

```
navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
```

Answer (score 10):

Put it in the `viewDidLoad` method

```
navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
```

Answer (score 6):

In SwiftUI

```swift
.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
```

Answer (score 4):

```swift
self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try with below code in **viewWillAppear** method.

> self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: true)

Read below link for more support.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/customizing_your_app_s_navigation_bar

Answer (score 3):

That worked for me in Swift 5 like a charm,
just add it to your viewDidLoad()

```
self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 3):

put the below code in `viewWillAppear` method.

```
navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a version of the answer in

### Swift 5

that you can use it from the storyboard:

```swift
// MARK: - Hiding Back Button

extension UINavigationItem {

    /// A Boolean value that determines whether the back button is hidden.
    ///
    /// When set to `true`, the back button is hidden when this navigation item
    /// is the top item. This is true regardless of the value in the
    /// `leftItemsSupplementBackButton` property. When set to `false`, the back button
    /// is shown if it is still present. (It can be replaced by values in either
    /// the `leftBarButtonItem` or `leftBarButtonItems` properties.) The default value is `false`.
    @IBInspectable var hideBackButton: Bool {
        get { hidesBackButton }
        set { hidesBackButton = newValue }
    }
}
```

Every navigation item of a view controller will have this new property in the top section of attributes inspector

Comment: It is wired, can not use self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: true) or self.navigationItem.hideBackButton = true, only if implement the extension.

Answer (score -6):

You may try with the below code

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer to this question.

Comment: his question is how to hide it not how to check if hidden

Comment: He asked about hiding the back button, not the navigation bar. he even showed the objective-C code that he was trying to mimic in Swift.

Answer (score -6):

[image]

Go to attributes inspector and uncheck show Navigation Bar to hide back button.