# I am unable to remove the back button from my Scrollview View Controller?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, back

I wish to remove the back button from my view controller.
[image: Remove book back button]

My ViewController also has a scroll view attached to it.
So far I have added the following code to my viewDidLoad():

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true;
    self.navigationController?.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = false;
    self.navigationController!.interactivePopGestureRecognizer!.isEnabled = false;
    self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated:true);


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

However even after running the program with this added code, the back button still does not go away for some reason. I would like to know how I would go about removing the back button.
Much appreciated

Comment: Do you want to remove the entire back button including the arrow, or just the text "Book"?

Comment: The entire back button @MikeTaverne

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift - How to hide back button in navigation item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27373812/swift-how-to-hide-back-button-in-navigation-item)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)
```