# Navigation Left Tab Bar Item

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

Hi in the app I'm building using Xcode 9.3.1 I have a navigation item titled "Home". In the next view controller, I have a sign out button in the top right corner, but I also have a "<- Home" button in the top left corner. I want to get rid of the "<- Home" button as it is unnecessary and doesn't conform to Apple's standards. Apparently, you can't delete the left tab bar item aka the (<- Home) button and I don't want to change the global tint as that would also hide the Sign out button I have in the top right corner.

[Pic_of_My_Build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LRZE.png)

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27373812/swift-how-to-hide-back-button-in-navigation-item

Comment: I went through the entire post and none of it worked. The one thing that actually worked deleted the entire bar, I only want the button that says "Home" and takes you back to the login screen either hidden or deleted.

Comment: Are you need to hide <Home button or what

Answer (score 0):

To hide back button:

add this in `ViewDidload` of your Target View controller `Race groups`

```
 let maskView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 40))
 maskView.backgroundColor = .clear
 self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: maskView)
```

Answer (score 0):

try in your viewDidLoad from RaceGroupsViewController

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
```

Another option is to change the type segue from show to present modally and set a NavigationController before RaceGroupsViewController

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by putting the view controller that said "Home" in front of my navigation controller and making the view controller that said "Home" the initial view.