# How to disable auto segue back to main screen in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, segue

When I create a new view controller, add a segue from the main screen to the new view controller. It seems that a default segue back to main screen is automatically created: When tap the upper part of the new view controller, it will go back to the main screen.
Where can I find the code or setting that does this "auto back"?
Thanks

[image]

Comment: It's unclear. Is it because you have a UINavigationController and you push new ViewController? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27373812/swift-how-to-hide-back-button-in-navigation-item ? Or make it so you present a newViewController with its own NavigationController?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Partial Curl Transition and want to disable back tap you can use it.

Create custom UIViewController subclass for presenting controller and use this code in it:

```
  private func removePartialCurlTap() {
      if let gestures = self.view.gestureRecognizers as? [UIGestureRecognizer] {
        for gesture in gestures {
          self.view.removeGestureRecognizer(gesture)
        }
      }
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
      super.viewDidAppear(animated)
      removePartialCurlTap()
    }
```

Comment: I don't have a Navigation Controller. I added a screenshot of my project in the original post

Comment: I don't understand, you have present segue , as I can see. As I can see on your screenshot when second controller will be present it will be no any buttons or clickable areas at the top to return back. So you should clarify you behavior to go back or attach your test project in question.

Comment: The second viewcontroller is empty. When I run the App. This is what happens: Tap "button", it goes into the second viewcontroller, but even second viewcontroller is empty, if I tap on the upper half of the screen, it will bring me back to the first viewcontroller.

Comment: Attach project to question, I really don’t understand how is it possible.

Comment: can you access the URL above?

Comment: @Paul yes, but there are no any segues in this proj

Comment: There is one added from the button to the red view controller. It's done in the story board. Thanks

Comment: I don't see anything in storyboard, just initial view controller without any segues.

Comment: I just found that this only happens when you select Partial Curl Transition.

Comment: Did you find the same thing? @Anton Rodzik

Comment: @Paul , yes , I'm seeing it. Are you sure that you need Partial Curl Transition? It's default apple transition and it's works in this way. If you don't want to go back from presenting controller by tap on top screen half you should use another one. For example cover vertical transition.

Comment: If you still want to use Partial Curl Transition - you can try code in my updated answer. (I've updated my answer)