# How to prevent segue back upon tapping screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-simulator

How do I prevent Xcode from preforming a segue back to previous view controller/screen when I tap on a screen.

When I click anywhere on a view controller/screen it sends me back to the previously viewed view controller/screen.

I've tested with the simulator and on a real iPhone and it does the same thing. Additionally, I've tested this by removing all segues in Xcode and it still sends me back to previous screen if I click anywhere.

**[UPDATE WITH CODE]**

View Controller #1:

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    // Button
    @IBAction func btn(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "SecondView", sender: self)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

There is then a segue added from View Controller #1 to View Controller #2 - a present modally with an identifier of "SecondView".

View Controller #2:

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't provided NEARLY enough information. How are you presenting the 2nd view controller? presenting it modally? Are you using a popover? What you describe is not normal behavior so you need to provide more information if you want us to help you.

Comment: Yes presenting the 2nd view controller modally. NOT a popover.

I'm just creating a View Controller. Then to that 1st View Controller I'm adding a button and adding an action trigger for the button to present modally the second View Controller. Then the 2nd View Controller is blank. Nothing on it... and if I click anywhere on that view/screen it sends me back to the 1st View Controller.

Comment: It would be nice if you post some screen shots of the storyboard with document outline pane open. So we can see what's exactly in these views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer to my question...

Here is the answer:

```
 private func removePartialCurlTap() {
  if let gestures = self.view.gestureRecognizers as? [UIGestureRecognizer] {
    for gesture in gestures {
      self.view.removeGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    }
  }
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
  super.viewDidAppear(animated)
  removePartialCurlTap()
}
```

The issue seems to be the transition used for the Seque, specially when using "Partial Curl" you get this issue. I'm guessing it's a bug in Xcode / iOS, or otherwise not documented well that if you use that specific transition you need to basically remove the GestureRecognizer so the user doesn't get sent back to the previous screen when they simple click someone on the screen.

Credit to [Anton Rodzik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5397625/anton-rodzik) for posting an answer to this here: [How to disable auto segue back to main screen in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52468998/how-to-disable-auto-segue-back-to-main-screen-in-xcode)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a full screen `UIButton` or a `UIGestureRecogniser` triggering a `dismiss(animated: Bool)` or an unwind segue.

Please share your code.

Comment: No, there is no full screen button. This happens when I create a new ViewControl in storyboard even with a blank screen.

Comment: Your code would run into an error because of an invalid redeclaration of the class ViewDogViewController

Comment: Ok, I've fixed that but still has the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I do not konw your detail code,just offer one method to do,use EventTouch or UITapGestureRecognizer can do it，in **View Controller #2**:
***EventTouch***

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
       dismiss(animated: Bool)
}
```

or ***UITapGestureRecognizer***

```
func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
   if sender.state == .ended {
    // handling code
    dismiss(animated: Bool)
   }
}
```

hope can help you.

Comment: That didn't seem to help... I get an error if I try either of those. But thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

hi first how the animation takes place I mean transition effect ,If it is from top to bottom then dismiss is firing , 
try view interaction enable is false for debugging purpose and post the result as reply