# Delete navigation item swift

Tags: ios, swift

How can I eliminate the navigation item that is created by default when doing a segue type show?[Create this navigation item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrWx5.png)

Comment: you need to hide your navigationbar from the navigationcontroller. And by default it removes the navigation bar from all the controllers, even from root controller. Now you can enable it by code or you can add your views or buttons in replace of navigation bar.

Comment: Thanks, you're right it worked for me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift - How to hide back button in navigation item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27373812/swift-how-to-hide-back-button-in-navigation-item)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true;
}
```