# Swift 5 - How to hide back button in Navigation bar or move to another screen without back button

Tags: ios, view, navigation, transition, swift5

I was having this issue and I've tried a lot of solutions that was proposed by some kind people here in the following topic:
[Swift - How to hide back button in navigation item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27373812/swift-how-to-hide-back-button-in-navigation-item)

I created a ViewController class:

```css
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: true)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
        //self.navigationItem.backButtonTitle = "hohoho"
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
        self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
        //UINavigationBar.appearance().isHidden = true
      
        //navigationItem.backBarButtonItem =  UIBarButtonItem(title: "Home/Return or nohing", style: .bordered, target: nil, action: nil)
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        
        self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: true)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
        //self.navigationItem.backButtonTitle = "hohoho"
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
        self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
        //UINavigationBar.appearance().isHidden = true
      
        //navigationItem.backBarButtonItem =  UIBarButtonItem(title: "Home/Return or nohing", style: .bordered, target: nil, action: nil)
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: true)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
        //self.navigationItem.backButtonTitle = "hohoho"
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
        self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
        //UINavigationBar.appearance().isHidden = true
      
        //navigationItem.backBarButtonItem =  UIBarButtonItem(title: "Home/Return or nohing", style: .bordered, target: nil, action: nil)
    }
}
```

and AS you can see in the above code I tried every single way with no change - back button still appear - then I try to make simple change like change the text of the back button or the shape and also there is no result!!

Am I do something wrong :( Because I feel like the whole class is not active for my view

Do I need to create an object of ViewController or something like that? Because I just wrote the mentioned code about my view code.

**MY GOAL: I just want to move from view to another with no back button if there is another way I wouldn't mind to do it.**

**PPLLLSSSS HELPP ME Guys I'm so tired,** I'll work on another things until find a solution for that and I'm sure there is a lot of people who want a solution for that issue.

Once I find the solution I'll share it with you guys :) Best Wishes and Regards

Comment: override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
       self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)
    }
put this code in the second view controller to which you segue into

Comment: @vrao I will try it again using your code

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem and the only solution that worked was adding
`.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)`  in my SwiftUI view

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add the below code in the ViewController where you want to hide the backbutton.

```
navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: true)
```

Comment: didn't work :( for me, but I really appreciate your effort and thank you, I think that I'm using it in a wrong way? may be this is the reason but IT TOOK me hours and hours without even changing anything in the nav bar :(

Comment: class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func btnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "testSegue", sender: self)}
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
           
    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "testSegue"{
            let viewController:ViewController2 = segue.destination as! ViewController2
        }}}

Comment: class ViewController2: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)
    }

Comment: I still dont understand why you would want to hide the back button?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Segue from viewController to viewController2 and name the segue testSegue. This should work.